# Kubernetes Executor in apache airflow: Pod getting deleted immediately with error

Tags: kubernetes, airflow

i am using apache airflow with KubernetesExecutor. I am running the setup in Minikube which is working fine that means whenever DAG triggers it generates pod for every task in the tag and delete the pod after task completion.

Same i have in test Kubernetes env but when i trigger DAG there, it create the pod for first task in the DAG and that pod gets deleted immediately from the state like.. ContainerCreating -> Running - > Completed -> Error -> Terminating. Airflow UI have logs empty for that task so not able to check what caused the issue and rest of the dependent task fails automatically.

Here are the env variables i am using

```
AIRFLOW__CELERY__CELERY_CONCURRENCY:
1
AIRFLOW__CELERY__FLOWER_URL_PREFIX:
AIRFLOW__CELERY__WORKER_CONCURRENCY:
1
AIRFLOW__CODE__ENABLE_XCOM_PICKLING:
false
AIRFLOW__CORE__CATCHUP_BY_DEFAULT:
false
AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_ARE_PAUSED_AT_CREATION:
false
AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_FOLDER:
/usr/local/airflow/dags
AIRFLOW__CORE__DONOT_PICKLE:
false
AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR:
KubernetesExecutor
AIRFLOW__CORE__EXPOSE_CONFIG:
true
AIRFLOW__KUBERNETES__DAGS_VOLUME_CLAIM:
airflow-dags
AIRFLOW__KUBERNETES__LOGS_VOLUME_CLAIM:
airflow-logs
AIRFLOW__KUBERNETES__NAMESPACE:
cap
AIRFLOW__KUBERNETES__WORKER_CONTAINER_REPOSITORY:
repo/airflow-latest
AIRFLOW__KUBERNETES__WORKER_CONTAINER_TAG:
latest
AIRFLOW__KUBERNETES__WORKER_PODS_CREATION_BATCH_SIZE:
9
AIRFLOW__WEBSERVER__BASE_URL:
http://localhost:8080
DO_WAIT_INITDB:
false
FERNET_KEY:
FLOWER_PORT:
5555
POSTGRES_DB:
airflow
POSTGRES_HOST:
airflow-postgresql
POSTGRES_PORT:
5432
REDIS_HOST:
airflow-redis-master
REDIS_PORT:
```

Comment: Hi, Check the log of the terminated pod, `kubectl logs -f $POD_NAME`, perhaps it will provide some information, also check the conditions on the status with the `kubectl get pods $POD_NAME -o yaml`

Comment: it says pod not found when i do that

Comment: I think,now the pod has been deleted, can you try to re run the DAG and do with new pods

Comment: the new pod gets deleted within seconds.. so its like by the time i will hit the pod logs, it will be deleted

Comment: If the pods directing their logs to stdout then you can use `-p` flag with the command to get the logs of previously terminated pods, try `kubectl logs -f $POD_NAME -p`

Comment: In addition to above you can also check the pod events `kubectl describe pod $POD_NAME` to see if anything error'd out on the kubernetes level.

Comment: I think, there will be some reason of certain condition such as termination in the status part of the yaml. can you post the status part here `kubectl get pods $TERMINATED_POD_NAME -o yaml` ?

Comment: same error pod not found

Comment: somehow got the logs from pod

ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'processor': [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/airflow/logs/scheduler' 

I have configured this property in env variable 
`"AIRFLOW__SCHEDULER__CHILD_PROCESS_LOG_DIRECTORY": "/tmp/airflow/logs/scheduler",`

still its using the older one

Comment: Can you put also "airflow_scheduler_child_process_log_directory" then put the same value in environment vaiable ?

Comment: I have already put this `AIRFLOW__SCHEDULER__CHILD_PROCESS_LOG_DIRECTORY` as `/tmp/airflow/logs/scheduler` in env variable as well as while building the image or do you mean to put the property with single underscore only ?

Answer (score 5):

you can add " AIRFLOW__KUBERNETES__DELETE_WORKER_PODS: false" environment variable and check pod logs